# android lint false alarm on missing permissions

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-lint, android-securityexception

Android lint keep reporting Missing Permissions even though I added @RequiresPermission on my method.
Code is:

```
 @NonNull
    @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    public static Map<String, Integer> selectContactVersions(@Nullable Collection<String> contactIds) {
        if (!PermissionUtils.isPermissonGranted(ApplicationKeeper.getApplication(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
            return Collections.emptyMap();
        }
```

Error report is:

```
AddressAccesssor.java:41: Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException
  38   @RequiresPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
  39   public static Map<String, Integer> selectContactVersions(@Nullable Collection<String> contactIds) {
  40       if (!PermissionUtils.isPermissonGranted(ApplicationKeeper.getApplication(), Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)) {
  41           return Collections.emptyMap();                                                          
  42       }


AddressAccessor.java:126: Call requires permission which may be rejected by user: code should explicitly check to see if permission is available (with checkPermission) or explicitly handle a potential SecurityException
 123       return Collections.emptyMap();
 124   }
 125 
 126   Map<String, List<String>> contactIdPhoneListMap = selectPhones(contactIds);                 
 127 
 128   Map<String, AddressbookContact> addressbookContactMap = new HashMap<String, AddressbookContact>();
 129   Cursor cursor = null;
```

Did I miss something here?

Answer (score 1):

> Did I miss something here?

Well, you missed a lot out there.

Permissions are required to be declared in manifest and needs to be requested in the **run-time**. Just suppressing the warning won't be enough.

Request the permissions explicitly to solve the problem.

Read the following documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting

Or simply use [my library.](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions)

Comment: Great library!. But I already requested the permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Starting from Android M, You will need to request the permissions in run-time too.